# What does 層 mean when referring to fans (the people)?

Tags: meaning, words

In this [article](https://jp.gamesindustry.biz/article/2102/21022201/), the author writes about Nintendo fans using 層 as a suffix:

「任天堂の最も忠実な**ファン層**がSwitchの長寿命化の鍵を握っている。」

「このような**層**を満足させるのはいつも難しい」

「任天堂はこの声の大きい**プレイヤー層**を狙っている。」

And, at last:

> 「任天堂は，**ファン層**という点では時間の余裕がある。」

In [Weblio's](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E5%B1%A4) definition, the indication of 層 as something related to position, status and class becomes clear, and there is even an example using the word 「ファン」 to describe a group/collective/assortment of people.

I can kinda get the usage of 層 in the first example here, where the author refers the "the **class** of fans ***which are the most passionate***", as well as the second and third where what kind of class is referred to is also clear. But the fourth one bugs me, ***which*** 層 exactly does he want to refer to here? Given the context, we know it's those "passionate kind of fans", but if that were to be a single phrase, would it still make sense?

Comment: Fan base. Target audience.

Comment: Did you know this is a translated article? [Here](https://www.gamesindustry.biz/articles/2021-02-19-nintendo-delivered-a-strong-direct-but-fan-impatience-grows-opinion) is the original article in English. I personally think the last one should have been translated simply as ファンベース rather than ファン層, so I understand your confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have correctly inferred, 層 refers to a specific layer/tier/(sub)group of people, especially a group of consumers that share the same characteristics/interest in some market. For example, 任天堂は新しいファン層を開拓した means Nintendo has developed a new fanbase by releasing a type of game they had never created (perhaps you could say this referring to FE Heroes). The first three examples of 層 you have cited are perfectly natural.

However, in the sentence in question, the word *fanbase* in [the original English article](https://www.gamesindustry.biz/articles/2021-02-19-nintendo-delivered-a-strong-direct-but-fan-impatience-grows-opinion) refers to Nintendo's fans as a whole, not a certain subgroup of (existing or potential) Nintendo fans. To be honest, 任天堂はファン層という点では時間の余裕がある in that context made little sense to me, so I think you can safely forget this translation. They could have translated this *fanbase* simply as ファンベース.

Answer (score 1):

In my own subjective experience, I've encountered 層【そう】 in reference to a "layer" of a particular **demographic**.  We don't talk about demographics as "layers" in English, so it might sound a bit funny, but in your sample texts they're essentially talking about those specific groups of people who are 1) ardent fans of Nintendo, 2) difficult to satisfy, 3) loud-mouthed () or influential, and 4) again, fans.

For your fourth example, a different way of looking at it might be this:

> Nintendo has some time to work with, since the company has so many fans.

Put more literally:

> 任天堂は，ファン層という点では時間の余裕がある。
> Nintendo `[TOPIC]`, fan demographic `[QUOT]` say point on `[TOPIC`] time `[POSSESSIVE]` margin `[SUBJECT]` exists. →
> Nintendo has a margin of time, in that [they] have a fan demographic.